# Animating background-color to transparent on IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm animating the `background-color` of a div via jQuery to `transparent`

```
$('div').animate('background-color', 'transparent');
```

which works fine on browsers, except for Internet Explorer 8. I know that `background-color: transparent` works fine for IE 8. Why is this not working when animating the value?

Thanks

Note: I've inspected the div with DevTools and for some reason the div is `rgb(255,255,255)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".div").attr('style', 'background-color: transparent');
```

This works for me.

Set this in a function, and trigger it anytime!

Comment: Just put transition before it.. $(".div").attr('style', 'transition: 2s; background-color: transparent');